# Count of top 10 products bought?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am having trouble getting the the count of the top 10 products bought. I am using MySQL 8.

I was given a table that includes the following column:

```
Product
-
Speakers, E book reader
Shoes, Sunglasses
Sports Magazine, Car Magazine
NULL
NULL
T-shirts
NULL
NULL
Shoes, Socks
None
```

What's the easiest way I can count the items?

Comment: Your products have very funny names.  Can you describe a "Shoes, Socks"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(product) AS product_count FROM table1 GROUP BY product ORDER BY product _count DESC LIMIT 10;
```